# Serverless endpoints for AWS SageMaker Foundation models?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

AWS offers these days some LLMs, which you can self-host using SageMaker endpoints.

Is it possible to create an serverless type endpoint for these models?

I didn't find answer for this in any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is if JumpStart foundational models are supported on Serverless endpoints then the answer is No, Serverless endpoints do not support GPUs currently and as such do not support foundation models.

Comment: Thanks! Seems AWS is currently quite ill-suited to create applications running any models needing (infrequent) real-time GPU inference

Comment: SageMaker does offer async inference that gives you the ability to scale down instances to zero.